# Windows - is there a way to see what apps spawn/use which processes?

Tags: windows, process

In a modern version of Windows (let's say, Vista - 10), is there a way to determine which apps spawn/use which processes, without having to install a 3rd party tool?

Comment: Microsoft offers a utility that does not need to be installed but does need to be downloaded called ProcessExplorer, which shows processes in a Tree View, indicating which processes are hosting other processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible to some extent in Windows 10 (not Vista) using the built-in Task Manager, though I don't find it very useful.  On the default Processes tab you can click the right-angle-bracket to expand to show the spawned processes, to some extent:

[image: Sample Child processes in Task Manager (Win10)]

Beyond that, it depends on your definition of "3rd party".  Since Microsoft acquired PSTools from SysInternals, Process Monitor is no longer "3rd party" and you can download it from Microsoft:
[Process Monitor download from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Process Monitor includes a load of detail (which you can filter to see only what you need to see) including Process Tree under the tools menu:

[image: ProcMon Tree tool]

The Process tree will show the spawned child processes as shown in the image below:

[image]